# IBIS model of capacitors

Tags: altium, signal-integrity, high-speed, ibis, hyperlynx

I have started the design of a high speed digital design multi-gbps interfaces.
I would like to use Altium designer for PCB analysis (signal integrity). But I am wondering if altium uses the IDEAL model of a capacitor for simulation. The impedance/frequency response of typical capacitors is something like the below figure
[image]

So the impedance/frequency characteristic is quite different than an IDEAL model (There is a parallel issue with inductors and partly resistors too). My Questions are:

1-Does Altium use ideal models for signal integrity analysis?

2-If the answer to 1 is Yes then why? To what degree results are valid?

3-What is the policy of HyperLynx in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer to the Altium part of your question.

Hyperlynx permits the use of a simple model (built in perfect capacitor), an IBIS model file (where you can define the parameters) or by using a [S-parameter model](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/45-10/s_parameters.html).

You can assign an IBIS model, S parameter or perfect capacitor from this dialog:

[image: Hyperlynx model selector]

S parameter models are available from [TDK](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/technicalsupport/tvcl/general/mlcc.html) and [AVX](http://www.avx.com/resources/design-tools/) and perhaps others; these will probably give you the best results for signal integrity. Hyerlynx supports the [Touchstone format](https://ibis.org/connector/touchstone_spec11.pdf).